# How to get the outlook folders size with PowerShell from Windows 8

Tags: exchange, powershell

I need to retrieve the size (in MB) of all folders of my mailbox(including sub-folders) with PowerShell (like the Outlook feature: Data File Proerties/Folder Size).

Is there a way to do that from my Workstation (Windows 8 Pro) with PowwerShell?

NB: Outlook is connected to Exchange Server 2013 (and I have no Exchange'administrator rights).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into  this for you trying out things with the Outlook.Application COM object, but found this article online that basically states what I've found so far.

[Checking deleted items folder size](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/01/28/how-can-i-notify-users-of-the-space-their-deleted-items-folder-is-using.aspx)

You can use their example to iterate various folders within Outlook, but I haven't gotten back to my workstation to check the Inbox folder size and see if it lines up with the size including subfolders or not, but I don't think it will.

Perhaps though the link can give you insight into modifying the PS script to what you are needing.